# Excel 2010 64 bit can't create .net object

Tags: c#, .net, vba, excel-2010

I have a simple class library that I use in Excel. Here is a simplification of my class...

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SimpleLibrary
{
 [ComVisible(true)]
 public interface ISixGenerator
 {
  int Six();
 }

 public class SixGenerator : ISixGenerator
 {
  public int Six() 
  {
   return 6; 
  }
 }
}
```

In Excel 2007 I would create a macro enabled workbook and add a module with the following code:

```
Public Function GetSix()
    Dim lib As SimpleLibrary.SixGenerator
    lib = New SimpleLibrary.SixGenerator
    Six = lib.Six
End Function
```

Then in Excel I could call the function GetSix() and it would return six. This no longer works in Excel 2010 64bit. I get a Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object.

I tried changing the platform target to x64 instead of Any CPU but then my code wouldn't compile unless I unchecked the Register for COM interop option, doing so makes it so my macro enable workbook cannot see SimpleLibrary.dll as it is no longer regsitered.

Any ideas how I can use my library with Excel 2010 64 bit?

Comment: And there are no native dependencies in your code? You should try to fix the problem that your code does not compile to x64. What error do you exactly get?

Comment: When I set my Platform target to x64 and have the Register for COM interop selected I get "File XXX is not a valid assembly". This error has been reported (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfx64bit/thread/253110bc-5fee-478f-a2eb-e1d5ec6039af) but the fix is to register manually. When I did this my macro enabled workbook still couldn't see the dll.

Comment: And you did use the 64-bit version of regasm? Did it register the assembly successfully, i.e. no error messages and the entries under HKCR get created?

Comment: Side note: Even though there is 64bit version of Office, Microsoft recommends the 32bit version unless you need Excel workbooks which are larger than 2gb. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681792(office.14).aspx

Comment: I registered with C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe. It registers fine but when I go to use the referenced assembly in VBA I get "Run-time error: Automation error. The system cannot find the file specified." I used ProcMon and it looks like it can't find the path in the registry.

Comment: Which path is Excel trying to access? Are you certain that Excel is indeed running as 64-bit application (check Task Manager or Excel's about box)? Otherwise I would try to check if for some reason Registry redirection might be a problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa384232%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't described in detail how your created your .NET assembly. However, there are a certain number of steps required to expose the assembly to COM:

- Add the following attributes to your code:

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

  namespace SimpleLibrary
  {
      [ComVisible(true)]
      [Guid("71F645D0-AA78-4447-BA26-3A2443FDA691")]
      public interface ISixGenerator
      {
          int Six();
      }

      [ComVisible(true)]
      [ProgId("SimpleLibrary.SixGenerator")]
      [Guid("8D59E0F6-4AE3-4A6C-A4D9-DFE06EC5A514")]
      [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
      public class SixGenerator : ISixGenerator
      {
          [DispId(1)]
          public int Six()
          {
              return 6;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Your assembly must be signed (*Project -> Properties... -> Signing*, create a strong key file and check the box to sign the assembly
- The following command is necessary to register the assembly (all in one line):

  ```
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe 
                    SimpleLibrary.dll /tlb SimpleLibrary.tlb /codebase
  ```

  This creates a .tlb type library file which you will have to reference from your VBA project (*Tools -> References -> Browse...* in your VBA editor)
- Adjust the VBA code:

  ```
  Public Function GetSix()
      Dim lib As SimpleLibrary.SixGenerator
      Set lib = New SimpleLibrary.SixGenerator
      GetSix = lib.Six
  End Function
  ```

You will find the steps described in more detail in this article on Microsoft's support database:

> **[How to call a Visual Basic .NET or Visual Basic 2005 assembly from Visual Basic 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817248)**

Comment: Thanks, this allows me to use my add-in with Excel 2010 64 bit. I'd like to use this add-in in any version of Excel. I might be asking to much, but is this possible?

Comment: After two weeks of torture, this is a godsend. 64 Bit Excel 2013 with COM Interop assemblies is a nightmare.