# VB.NET 64bit COM with c# referenced helper assembly class

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, 64-bit, com-interop

have a VB.net 64 bit project to be referenced in Excel 64 bit.  I have a c# helper class that is referenced by the VB.net project.  I have all the projects signed and the VB.net project set for Make Com Visible.  It builds and runs fine.  **When I set my VB.net project to Register for COM interop i get an error.**

Error   120 Cannot register assembly "E:\KSP\KSP\SealData\bin\x64\Debug 64***[VB].dll". Could not load file or assembly '[C# Assembbly name], Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c89dd9761ce81049' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.    SealDataStage

The C# project is signed C# and is refed in the VB project.  At some point I got it to compile and the setup project created the files and a tlb for the VB.net project.  Now I cannot get it to build again.  I have looked in the GAC and I do not see my dll in the list.  So I don't see how it would be a gac conflict. But I cannot figure out what to do.

This is the post I am following to get the solution to work with Excel.
http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/a-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-excel/

**Updated information:**
I have tried the following.

1. Refed the Helper dll
2. Every possible combination of com and signed.
3. I used the same key for signing across the projects and different ones

**I got it to work Sort of:**  I opened the project in 2012. It allows me to register COM and not be signed.  If i Sign the projects it gives me the same error as 2010.  So I am guessing this is a signing issue.  I read you can manually register an unsigned dll or GAC it if its signed. I can manually add the dlls to the setup project from 2010. I would prefer to build and work with this in 2010 for the setup project.

**Working Solution**
This post got me the answer and is in c#
[Excel 2010 64 bit can't create .net object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724387/excel-2010-64-bit-cant-create-net-object)

**The combination of COM settings and manually registering the dlls was the key.  Follow the answer in the post above and MAKE SURE YOU DO NOT CHECK THE REGISTER COM OPTION**  You then have to use the 64bit regasm util. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm "C:\Program Files\Default Company Name\KSP_Setup******.dll" /tlb /codebase

**The signing problem was solved**-----I renamed the C# project. Then I kept getting an error about the old dll name not being found on compile with signed assembly.  I recreated all the strong name keys and it compiled.  It also now works in VS2010 and the Setup project works and registers the Com dll.  In the setup project on the COM dll, set the properties to register it.

My Solution is in VB.net "Eck, I dislike working in VB"  Anyway I figured id post the working details. I must say there is a lot of misinformation running around.  I banged my head for several days on this.  The method ConvertByteArrayToSingleArray is to fix the way com returns the arrays as objects.

Make sure you runs Visual Studio as Administrator

I set all compile options to 64 bit for both projects through configuration manager. 
Made Com enabled for the VB and the c# did not require com.

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On
Imports UpgradeUtils.Activex
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<Guid("1F249C84-A090-4a5b-B592-FD64C07DAB75"), _
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)> _
Public Interface IclsSealDataStage
    <DispId(1)> Function SetStages(ByRef Starts As Object, ByRef Ends As Object, ByRef Cnt As Integer, ByRef XTIME As Object, ByRef YTORQUE As Object, ByRef YDP As Object, ByRef YOILLEVEL As Object, ByRef YOILTEMP As Object, ByRef YSPEED As Object) As Object
    Sub RegisterInitGlobalVarsDelegates()
End Interface

<ComVisible(True), _
Guid("E42FBD03-96DF-43a7-A491-23E735B32C5C"), _
ProgId("SealDataStage.clsSealDataStage"), _
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)> _
Public Class clsSealDataStage
    Inherits ComponentClassHelper
    Implements IclsSealDataStage

    Public Function SetStages(ByRef Starts As Object, ByRef Ends As Object, ByRef Cnt As Integer, ByRef XTIME As Object, ByRef YTORQUE As Object, ByRef YDP As Object, ByRef YOILLEVEL As Object, ByRef YOILTEMP As Object, ByRef YSPEED As Object) As Object Implements IclsSealDataStage.SetStages

        Dim oStarts As Array = ConvertByteArrayToSingleArray(Starts)
        Dim oEnds As Array = ConvertByteArrayToSingleArray(Ends)
        Dim oXTIME As Array = ConvertByteArrayToSingleArray(XTIME)
        Dim oYTORQUE As Array = ConvertByteArrayToSingleArray(YTORQUE)
        Dim oYDP As Array = ConvertByteArrayToSingleArray(YDP)
        Dim oYOILLEVEL As Array = ConvertByteArrayToSingleArray(YOILLEVEL)
        Dim oYOILTEMP As Array = ConvertByteArrayToSingleArray(YOILTEMP)
        Dim oYSPEED As Array = ConvertByteArrayToSingleArray(YSPEED)

        Form1.DefInstance.PlotData(oXTIME, oYTORQUE, oYDP, oYOILLEVEL, oYOILTEMP, oYSPEED)
        'Form1.pg_MouseDown Starts(), Ends()
        Form1.DefInstance.starts_ends(oStarts, oEnds, Cnt)

        Form1.DefInstance.ShowDialog()
        Return VB6.CopyArray(stages) 'Oddly enough these are not suppose to work in 64 but do????

    End Function

    Private Function ConvertByteArrayToSingleArray(ByVal Starts As Object) As Array
        Dim obj As Object = DirectCast(Starts, Object)
        Dim ct As Array = DirectCast(obj, Array)
        Dim content As Single() = New Single(ct.Length) {}
        ct.CopyTo(content, 0)
        Return ct
    End Function
```

I really hope this saves someone from the days I lost. :-)  If I did help drop a line here. I will check back every once in a while.

Comment: Just for good measure can you try removing the reference to UpgradeHelpers.VB6 from your SealDataStage projdct and then just add it again as a reference.   Will it build now?

Comment: Try to create a small demo .net 64bit that is referencing UpgradeHelpers.VB6, and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference a 32 bit assembly from a 64 bit application or assembly.

If you have an assembly that you require registering for Interop this *must* be 32 bit. You cannot register it as a COM component otherwise

Comment: Everything is either 64 or a .net reference.  All the projects are 64 bit.

Comment: @SteveColeman - You cannot register a 64 bit assembly for COM interop hence the problem you stated in you post. There is no way round this. COM is build on a 32 bit framework.

Comment: Matt, I cannot find anything to support your claim that 64 bit office will not work with a 64 bit com dll.  I have found several post about do specifically that. http://www.ironshay.com/post/Developing-Excel-Functions-in-C-for-Excel-2010-64-Bit.aspx